# How to convert pdf to html in django?

Tags: python, jquery, django

I know how to convert html to pdf using python packages and in jquery, but i have a task to perform the opposite, i want exact html from a pdf. How to do so? Is there any jquery or python package or method in which i can do so?

Comment: A quick google showed up https://pypi.org/project/pdftotree/, which looks worth a look

Comment: Hi,i have tried it,i'm using python 3.6.5 and pdftotree package may be not supporting it as giving error that `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow` .

Comment: pdftotree does not support python 3.6 or above. my setup is running on python 3.6.6, so cant use it.